# Error while creating a toggle-like setup for a video from image in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onclick, toggle

I have been doing a project: a Netflix clone using React JS. I have been trying to make it as much dynamic as possible with giving a onclick() function for the image of the movie:

- as we click the image we get the trailer for the movie
- as we click on the image again, then the trailer must go

The vanishing of trailer is not working in the code. Been trying many ways to do.

This is what happens when we click on the image :

[image: This is what happens when we click on the image]

The trailer comes, but when clicked again it doesn't vanish!

This is the code which I tried

```
return (
    <div className='row'>
      <br />
        <h2>{props.title}</h2>
        <br />

        <div className="posters"> {
          movie.map((obj) =>
 
          <img onClick = {()=> setShowTrailer((!showTrailer) ? handleMovieTrailer(obj.id) : null)}
          className={ props.isSmall ? 'post_small' : 'Poster'} 
          src={`${imageURL + obj.poster_path}`} alt="Poster" />
          )
          
        }
        </div>

         { urlId  && <YouTube videoId = {urlId.key} opts = {opts}/> }
    </div>
  )
```

The useState which I used

```
  const [showTrailer, setShowTrailer] = useState(false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the method `handleMovieTrailer` returns?
Tried to emulate this flow, you can check it out here...
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-wing-g3sg7e?file=/src/App.js
Try returning a value from `handleMovieTrailer`

Comment: Actually the `handleMovieTrailer` doesn't return any value, it is used to get the id of the image as we click.

Comment: It takes the id from the image and is used to get the corresponding video of the clicked image by storing the id in the state, and using it in another API .

Comment: Can you check the response of `(!showTrailer) ? handleMovieTrailer(obj.id) : null)` and see whether it returns a boolean or undefined. What I'm trying(codesandbox link), I'm getting it undefined and hence value of the `showTrailer` not updating.

Comment: Same here. It shows undefined.

Comment: That's the problem. I tried returning from `handleMovieTrailer` method, and it's working fine. You can check it in [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-wing-g3sg7e?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Ya, now the value is changing, but still the trailer is not vanishing ! ?

Comment: Is `{ urlId  && <YouTube videoId = {urlId.key} opts = {opts}/> }` the part which is playing trailer clip? If yes, try `{ urlId && showTrailer  && <YouTube videoId = {urlId.key} opts = {opts}/> }`